# Getting error while executing angular universal app

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular13

I am working angular 13 application and trying to integrate universal.
I have followed the official document https://angular.io/guide/universal to integrate.

Angular version

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.8
Node: 14.19.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.17
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.3.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.8
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.8
@angular/cdk                    13.3.9
@angular/cli                    13.3.8
@angular/material               13.3.9
@nguniversal/builders           13.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.1.1
@schematics/angular             13.3.8
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.6.4
```

After integrating all when I hit the "ng run Frontend:serve-ssr" command in a terminal, then I get the following error.

Error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: null
at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
at onParseError (internal/url.js:270:9)
at new URL (internal/url.js:346:5)
at new InitServ (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:51443:17)
at Object.InitServ_Factory [as factory] (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:52031:10)
at R3Injector.hydrate (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:241212:35)
at R3Injector.get (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:241031:33)
at injectInjectorOnly (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:234492:33)
at ɵɵinject (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:234496:61)
at injectArgs (/home/pc5/Documents/Restucture/frontend-universal/dist/Frontend/server/main.js:234576:23)
```

Comment: can you please reproduce the problem in a small project and share it on github, or give us the part you think is causing the problem, we can't help you with only the error

Comment: There is not enough info to debug on our side. I advise you to make a minimal project and integrate universal and when everything is ok, add little by little all your components. If even the MVP doesn't work, then you can make a demo with it so we can try

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have converted all relative paths to absolute.

to use angular universal and take advantage of it's utilities like prerendering, you need to follow a set of rules. [Check it out !](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/docs/gotchas.md)

As server side do not have some objects defined like `document`, `window`, `localstorage` and ...
when your code will be first rendered in server side, it will not be recognized and causes errors.

My personal suggestion how ever is to use `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document)` logic, hence you will use document object only in client side.

I used domino and didn't worked for me ...