# Angular 13 SSR Build Serve eror -- ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular13

```
var canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
                    ^
```

ReferenceError: document is not defined
at C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:64680:25
at C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:64682:4
at Object.13504 (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:64786:3)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:224497:42)
at Module.16720 (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\ArteryUniversal\server\main.js:5796:71)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:224497:42)
at Module.90158 (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:488:121)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:224497:42)
at Module.36747 (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:641:77)
at **webpack_require** (C:\Users\aakas\Desktop\ArteryUniversal\dist\Universal\server\main.js:224497:42)

Answer (score 0):

I have answered it in [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72846235/19470950)

You can use `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document)` for that matter.